# Site abre mas não carrega os ficheiros cs, js, png etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

Fiz migração do VS2012 para VS2017, e na minha solução tenho 3 sites, 2 dos quais corro e não tenho problema e no outro quando faço debug ele abre mas toda a parte de Design não é carregada(css, js, png, etc). 
Vendo o log da página no Fiddler tenho 2 erros que são eles

1)
IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error

2)

This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application.
  In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

If you see the text "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined", 
  this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4.  If you are running WebMatrix, to resolve this problem, 
  go to the Settings node to set the .NET Framework version to ".NET 2". You can also remove the extra sections from the web.config file.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,19,0x800700b7,16299)

Alguem sabe como resolver isto. Já ando de volta disto à 2 dias e ainda não achei solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução do meu problema. Tive que remover o seguinte código do Web.config

```
 <staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```